# How can I create a view to display a secondary tab on a node?

Tags: views

Using views I can create a page with the nid as context and place a primary tab alongside the "View" and "Edit" tab on a node. How can I move it to the seconday tab on the "View" page?

e.g. What I can get

[image]

What I need

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a View page with path

```
node/%/view/secondary-task
```

Make it a "Default task" or "Default menu tab" in the View menu settings.

Comment: Nope. that wasn't it. :(

Comment: Ok, you might also need another tab path below that one at node/%/view/secondary-task/action

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, as the menu structure is missing a menu item.

I have altered a default view the Views module to be visible on node/%/view/backlinks, instead of node/%/backlink; I also changed its menu type to menu tab for an existing menu. The view was not shown.

I then added the following code in my test module.

```
function code_testing_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/view/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'View', 
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'weight' => -10,
  );
}

function code_testing_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'menu_alter') {
    $group = $implementations['code_testing'];
    unset($implementations['code_testing']);
    $implementations['code_testing'] = $group;
  }
}
```

Once I did that, the view was correctly rendered as sub-tab.

[image: screenshot]

In short, showing a view as sub-tab is possible, if there is already a sub-tab. Differently, the view will not be visible.